# Проблема с выводом CMD из rstcli64

Tags: cmd, raid, intel, zabbix

Для мониторинга *RAID-контроллера* от *Intel* я использую утилиту *rstcli*.
Утилита прекрасная и выводит всю информацию, которая мне нужна.

Собственно команда выглядит так:

```
rstcli64 --information | find /i "State" | find /i "Normal" /c
```

При выполнении этой команды я получаю

```
0 
3
```

где 0 - означает, что команда введена с правильными ключами
а 3 - результат, который мне нужен.

Это значение мне необходим отдать *Zabbix-агенту*, который принимает только число, и ничего кроме числа.

Как избавиться от этого нуля...?

Есть вариант с записью в файл, но он не подходит.

Comment: в *gnu/linux* это решается добавкой ещё одного компонента конвейера: `... | tail -n 1`, который возвратит только последнюю строку. в *ms/windows*, возможно, подойдёт [совет](http://stackoverflow.com/a/187982/4827341) по установке дополнения, в котором присутствует эта программа `tail`.

Answer (score 1):

Скачал драйвер с cli отсюда:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ru/download/23257/Intel-RSTe-AHCI-SCU-Software-RAID-driver-for-Windows-

Написал практически так же как Вы

```
UserParameter=RAIDstate,"c:\Program Files\Zabbix\utils\rstcli64" --information -v | find /i "State" | find /i "Normal" /c
```

работает правильно, возвращает одну цифру, возможно дело в версии утилиты